# Load a row value from a database

Tags: android, database, android-edittext

**-----------------------SOLVED-----------------------**

How can I load the values ​​as the row that the users  selected? Like this:

[image: Database example]

If the user select test (from a Spinner) set EditText to the value, but have more than one value to more than one EditText.

```
// Labels Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_VALUE = "value";

public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return label}


 // MainActivity Spinner
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label ,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

PS: I have the Spinner loaded and database created.

PS²: The user will create the database keys, so I don't know the name of key "name".

Comment: create model class for your db row, query database and create list of your model class object and fill values. now access the row by getting the position

Comment: The user will create the database tables, so I don't know the name of table "name"  -- then you will need to set up another table that records the users table name(s)so you know the name

Comment: The user will save your name and the value will get it from EditText. So, when the user select the table name, the values from the row will loaded from the row name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the column keys, you can use this following code.

```
SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
mDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor dbCursor = mDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
```

Comment: @Crimeiaman `public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`. Here we are passing null for columns[], selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit as we doesn't know the columns.

Comment: Ow, ok. And How i can load value from selected column?

Comment: Replace the first null with string array, containing column names.

Comment: And load from a selected key "name" from a Spinner?

Comment: @Crimeiaman `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });` here on itemSelected you will get the position and from that position you can retrieve the selected column from array and fire database query

Comment: No :/ i don't know how I can grab a row value